# vim - how to stop this bug: insert single char func - put vs p

Tags: vim, time, mapping

I wanted to be able to easily insert a single char from normal mode, and clean up some of the mappings that were being added for that purpose while I was at it. I have this in my vimrc now:

```
 "insert single char from normal mode
function! InsertSingleChar()
    "jump into insert mode and place character after the cursor
   let l:char = getchar()
   if l:char != 0 
     silent! exec "normal a" . nr2char(l:char)
   endif
 endfunction
```

But the only way to input a p is to wait for it to time out then type it in, or it puts instead.

I call this using the following map:

```
nnoremap <leader>j :call InsertSingleChar()<cr>
```

How can I fix it? Appreciated.

I had a mapping and forgot about it, when I searched to be sure I mistyped and missed it. Sorry everyone! Thanks for the help

Comment: How are you calling this? It seems to work for me

Comment: I'll update with a little more info

Comment: This is also works for me. I map with: `:nnoremap <silent> I :call InsertSingleChar()<Enter>`

Comment: I tried to prefix my mapping with silent but it makes no difference. I don't recall what silent is supposed to do either so I'll look that up

Comment: doesn't seem like silent should make a difference.

Comment: Silent just for convenience, so the function called is hidden. Your problem is not quite clear. Perhaps you can try add `<nowait>` in place of `<silent>` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you only have a problem with the insertion of `p`; other letters work fine.

This sounds like you have a `jp` mapping that is preferred by Vim, so you have to type `j` (timeout) `p` to apply your mapping with a value of `p`, and not trigger the `jp` mapping instead.

You can check via

```
:verbose nmap jp
```

and then probably would have to remap that one to use a second non-printable character, e.g. `j<C-P>` instead.

Comment: You're right, I forgot I had a mapping and when I did a search I had a typo so it missed it. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: I've changed the <leader>jp mapping but it still has the same behaviour. It works after quitting and relaoding. But for future reference, how do I make it update without quitting? I already auto source the vimrc

Comment: You need to restart, or explicitly `:nunmap <Leader>jp` in the current session.

Comment: Thanks, good tip for future! hopefully neoVim will have a more intuitive approach to this.